# Installing VSTO Outlook addin for All Users to drive other than C: results in Microsoft Office Customization Installer dialog

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, .net-security

First let me get this stuff out of the way:

- This happens with my own addin, as well as another third party VSTO add-in, so I don't think I'm doing anything incorrect
- .net 4.0. VSTO runtime 10.0.50701
- Windows 8. Also tried Windows 7
- I am using the `|vstolocal` suffix in the HKLM registry for the addin
- I have also tried adjusting the 'program files' paths in the registry here: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion` to point to my new 'F:' location, and that didn't change any behavior

Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. Create a new volume on a separate disk other than C:. I called mine 'F:'
2. Add the program files structures F:\program files and F:\program files (x86)
3. Install your VSTO addin (I'm using Outlook but it will happen with Word too) to "F:\program files (x86)" instead of the 'C:' drive
4. Launch Outlook.

Result is this dialog:
[image]

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767(VS.100).aspx), I shouldn't be getting this since its an all users install (see the Inclusion List section):

Is this a Microsoft issue? I realize I can add to the Inclusion myself however then I would be subscribing to more of a per-user approach, and that seems like a bad approach. Is this coming up because anything other than the 'real' program files folder cannot really be trusted by VSTO loader?

Answer (score 1):

The dialog window belongs to the ClickOnce installer. But the link goes to the Windows Installer section in MSDN.

It is up to you where to install the add-in, there is no need to use the **Program Files** folder.

Make sure that you did all the steps described in the [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) article. It describes all the required steps for creating add-in installers.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that dialog 'belonging' to ClickOnce, but that's not the issue. I didn't miss any steps for creating the installers, that is pretty trivial. I agree I can install it anywhere, I'm just sticking to program files for convention.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through the same thing, i got this when i just published the vsto from vs2015. I tried using installshield, yielded the same issues, eventually i switched to wix installer, now i don't have any update checks running and its a clean install. These are some customization updates and our client actually had a firewall blocking it so the install failed. Try wix it worked great for me. Hopefully you don't end up with my current issue of not seeing the add-in if i am not running outlook as Administrator, driving me nuts, good luck.